# Is there a simple proof that the following is zero for all x?

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin(2\pi x/3)+2 \sin(2\pi(x-1)/3)+\sqrt{3}\cos(2\pi x/3)$

[wolfram alpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(2x%20pi%2F3)%2B2%20sin(2(x-1)%20pi%2F3)%2Bsqrt(3)cos(2x%20pi%2F3))

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Thoughtful questions, even homework-related, are welcome. However, you should not expect others to do your homework for you, and it's inappropriate to post your homework verbatim. (That may not be what you're doing, but all people here can go by is appearances, including the appearance that posters have made a good faith effort. I expect that's why your question has gotten downvotes.) Instead, please try to ask questions about specific places where you're stuck, or about particular concepts you don't understand.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang it is not very appropriate to acuse people of posting homework; especially when the post is clearly not homework. Asking why something that might not even be reducable equals 0 is certainly not homework.

Comment: well, thanks guys, it was obviously a temporary brain freeze on my part, i would not mind if this question was deleted, not sure how though. The question is related to this http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31608/adaptive-filter-with-two-inputs/31664

Comment: @DeLorean88 It is not respectful to delete a question once an answer has been given.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: The disclaimer "That may not be what you're doing..." was intended to forestall your interpretation, but I'll reword my boilerplate file.

Comment: @OlivierOloa he assumes that if an answer is homework it needs to be instantly deleted. He is a brand new off the assembly line user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One has
$$
\sin (a-b)=\sin a \cos b - \sin b \cos a
$$ giving here
$$
\sin(2\pi(x-1)/3)=\sin(2\pi x)\cos(2\pi/3)-\sin(2\pi/3)\cos(2\pi x)
$$ then use
$$
\cos(2\pi/3)=-1/2,\quad \sin(2\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}/2.
$$